# Why did my answer get deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

I posted an answer on [a question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8930/are-rotton-apples-edible)
and it got deleted. I would like to know who did it and what was wrong with my answer? The answer was

> @Bulldogg6404 said that C is the only valid conclusion.
>   Well, even C is not valid since we do not know that apples are food.
>
> Therefore, the answer is none of these.

Comment: Could you please include your answer also, since many users might not have seen that particular post.

Comment: oops!! thanks for telling... i completely forgot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was actually one of them (or maybe **the** one) who flagged it for deletion, so I guess you get an explanation directly from the source!

I flagged it as low quality for a few reasons actually.

---

**A)** This is the main reason. I figured it was unrealistic, and kinda ridiculous, no offence. I admit this may be *KIND* of in scope, if it was [lateral-thinking](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking) but it wasn't.

**B)** It was more like a comment. You were directing a comment to *Bulldogg6404*, this would've been better as a comment to his answer.

**C)** Your answer was not quite in scope, well actually, it wasn't in scope *at all*. You said none of these, that was not an available option.

**D)** You had very little explanation as to why this answer worked, and you gave absolutely no reason as to why you believe it worked for this question, keeping in mind *C)*

---

I hope this helped as to answer your question, next time keep in mind how the community will most likely react to your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your answer was essentially

> we do not know that apples are food.

This is not an answer so much as a sarcastic comment; hence, it was flagged as Very Low Quality and I deleted it.

Comment: I beg to differ but I in no way was being sarcastic. Moreover, nowhere in the question is it mentioned that apples are a subcategory/part of food, hence, I reached the conclusion that none of the options provided by the person who posted the question were correct.Now, either there is a fault in the question or you have misinterpreted/misunderstood my answer and hence made a mistake by deleting the same.
And even if you believe the question is correct, all I am asking for is a justification, is that too much?

Comment: @The Dragonista I flagged it, see my answer.

Comment: @TheDragonista In what universe are apples *not* food? Does each and every word of a puzzle have to be explicitly defined? See also: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1334/39

Comment: @Doorknob I think my a seer sums up my reasoning quite nicely.

Comment: We can't just assume stuff!! What if that is the trick in the puzzle??
(P.S- Mate, who's being sarcastic now?)

Comment: @TheDragonista At that point, what stops one from answering, say, [how do you get the sword on the train](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/3013/39) with "stab the conductor"? Please read the meta post I linked. (Sorry if you feel that way, but I'm not trying to use any sarcasm here.)

Comment: Type correction in last comment: answer* @The Dragonista if there **were** a trick like this, it would be tagged *lateral-thinking* or *brainteaser* or *trick*

Comment: Hmm... except that this is a syllogism. All assumptions need to be stated; a proper formation would include "all apples are food" and "all food is either edible or inedible". But then it's not a puzzle, per se. I honestly think the answer was only poor because the question was worse.

Comment: Should [this answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9900/thirteen-politicians/9926#9926) be deleted for the same reason? I haven't flagged it yet, but it seems to meet the same criteria for 'Very Low Quality'.